# UILabel's inside UITableViewCell not resizing when orientation changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm populating my UITableView with cells that contain two UILabel's: one of them being the title and the other one being the content. I'm calculating their sizes in heightForRowAtIndexPath: and everything seems cool until I change the orientation. When I change the orientation, the size of each label doesn't seem to change. For example if I'm changing from portrait to landscape, the expected behaviour is to see label's with smaller height (assuming it's a multi-line label). However, the labels' heights remain the same and I get an ugly, disoriented view. The code I've written for this is as follows:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat tableWidth = [tableView bounds].size.width;

    ListItem* glossaryItem;
    if ([tableView isEqual:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView])
    {
        glossaryItem =(ListItem*)[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        glossaryItem =(ListItem*)[self.glossary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    NSString* name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p><b>%@</b> :</p>", glossaryItem.name];

    NSString* content = glossaryItem.details[0];
    NSAttributedString* nameWithStyle = [HTMLParser parseText:name withFontSize:16 withFontType:@"Light"];

    NSAttributedString* contentWithStyle = [HTMLParser parseText:content withFontSize:16 withFontType:@"Light"];

    CGRect nameRect = [nameWithStyle boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(screenWidth - 40, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) context:NULL];

    CGRect contentRect = [contentWithStyle boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(screenWidth - 40, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) context:NULL];

    return nameRect.size.height + contentRect.size.height + 33;
}
```

HTMLParser is a class I wrote to parse text's in HTML format into attributed strings. I'm guessing the problem here is the label's sizes are not recalculated after orientation change. If I add the following code, everything looks fine but this takes too much time for tables with a lot of cells.

```
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

How can I work around this? I can provide the constraints of my labels if needed.

Comment: Have you tried calling layoutIfNeeded on your tableview?

Comment: I did. Instead of [self.tableView reloadData] I wrote [self.tableView layoutIfNeeded] but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Setup autoLayout constraints 
or, continue to call the reloadData the way you are doing on didRotate... 
but size the labels in cellForRow... like below

Set the height for row only in heightForRowAtIndexPath

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//Some identifier and recycling stuff

if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
    //Make labels smaller
}
else {
    //Make them longer
}

// save the calculated height for the label
```

//and size your tableviewrow height accordingly in heightForRowAtIndexPath
}

Comment: As I said, reloading all data takes too much time. And setting frames by checking the orientation is not a good way of solving things.

Comment: Hopefully the self sizing cells in iOS8 will resolve this problem for you. I do not have other solution for it currently.